# Why is my in (?) clause running the sql id in ('1,2,3') instead of id in (1,2,3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string

```
"1,2,3"
```

in a varialbe, I am doing:

```
User.where("id in (?)", user_id_list)
```

resulting sql is:

```
select users.* from users where (id in ('1,3,4'))
```

I want:

```
select users.* from users where (id in (1,3,4))
```

How to fix this?

does `user_id_list` have to be an array?

Comment: Have you tried making it an array instead? That's something you can test yourself.

Comment: Try: `"1,2,3".split(",").map{|e| e.to_i}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass in a string value, rails will wrap it with quotes, which is why you see your results.

When you have an array, you can just do:

```
User.where(:id => user_id_list)
```

and Rails will automatically create the IN clause for you.

Since those are user id's with integers, I would suggest just doing:

```
User.where(:id => user_id_list.split(',').map(&:to_i))
```

Comment: I've found that the `.split(",")` part causes problems for me with Rails + Postgres. But it works fine if I remove it and just do the equivalent of `user_id_list.map(&:to_i)`. Thanks for the fix @Mike Lewis!